# Error inserting query into database with jdbc

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

in my application I'm trying to insert a query into an oracle database using jdbc. I create this table:

```
create table TMP
(
SYNC       NUMBER,
USER       VARCHAR2(50),
DAT       DATE
)
```

And I use this code to insert an entry:

```
PreparedStatement stat=null;

    try {
        dbStatement = dbConnection.createStatement();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO TMP (USER, DAT) Values (?,?);";

        for (ReplicationHistoryDetailVO tmpEntry : entry) {
            if (tmpEntry.getSyncPhase() == REPLICATION_PHASE.DOWNLOAD) {
                stat=dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stat.setString(1, "David");
                stat.setDate(2, new Date(tmpEntry.getFinishTime()));
                stat.executeUpdate();               
            }
        }
```

From this code I have the following error:

```
Error updating database java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911
```

The connection is ok. I must to write only two values, because the first value is an autoincremental key and I don't set this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `"INSERT INTO TMP (USER, DAT) Values (?,?)"` without the ; at the end.

```
ORA-00911 is a common error for common syntax mistakes.
```